# Set image baseline within a flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a multi-column layout using flexbox and align the baselines in all columns. I do this using the `align-items: baseline` property. Now this works great when the first element in each column is text, such as the following:

**CSS**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline; 
}

.col-2 {
  width: 48%;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class='container'> 
  <div class='col-2'>
    <h2>Nullam eget metus suscipit, auctor diam quis, sagittis eros. Phasellus quis iaculis nisi.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col-2'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis nulla in elit hendrerit congue. Nullam eleifend, neque vitae finibus accumsan, augue dui lacinia leo, eget sagittis ipsum dui id leo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I run into is when the first element in a column is an image, like so:

```html
<div class='container'> 
  <div class='col-2'>
    <h2>Nullam eget metus suscipit, auctor diam quis, sagittis eros. Phasellus quis iaculis nisi.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col-2'>
    <img src='https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/644/23373656961_9d6426d815_h.jpg'>
  </div>
</div>
```

The heading in the first column aligns with the bottom of the image in the second column. What I would like to do is change the image baseline so that the heading will move towards the top of the column. I'm aware that you can resolve this issue by setting the `align-items` property to `flex-start`, but I would prefer to leave the `align-items` property as is. That way the text baselines will always align no matter how many columns there are.

My goal - figure out how to adjust the image baseline without changing the `.container` class. Is this possible?

Here's a codepen you can play around with http://codepen.io/jonathink/pen/wMwgwZ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I would like to do is change the image baseline so that the heading will move towards the top of the column.
>
> My goal - figure out how to adjust the image baseline without changing the `.container` class. Is this possible?

You can create a class for images and then use the [**`align-self`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) property to adjust the alignment of images only.

*From your [codepen](http://codepen.io/jonathink/pen/wMwgwZ):*

**Revised HTML** (added `.image` class in two places)

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col-2'>
    <h2>Nullam eget metus suscipit...</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col-2'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col-2'>
    <h2>Nullam eget metus suscipit...</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col-2 image'><!-- ADJUSTMENT HERE -->
    <img src='https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/644/23373656961_9d6426d815_h.jpg'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <h2>Nullam eget metus suscipit...</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-3 image'><!-- ADJUSTMENT HERE -->
    <img src='https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/644/23373656961_9d6426d815_h.jpg'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Revised CSS** (added one rule)

```
.image { align-self: flex-end; }
```

[**Revised DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQzvmq)

Comment: That's close. There's a problem where if a text column is taller than a column containing an image, the image get's aligned to the bottom. I've fixed this by setting the **align-self** property to **flex-start**.

Comment: Yeah, not knowing your overall purpose for the layout, I didn't test every use-case scenario. But the key is to apply the `align-self` property to the image, so they could be aligned independently of the text.

Comment: I just want to add that I would prefer not to add a class to the column '<div>' and instead edit the CSS affecting the '<img>'. After further experimenting, I stumbled upon a solution using **inline-block** and **vertical-align** properties. 

[Ideal SOLUTION](http://codepen.io/jonathink/pen/mVbjxo)

Thanks for your help @Michael_B

Comment: LOL! I had a `vertical-align` solution on the image, but chose instead to stick with the flex method. Glad you got it resolved. Take care.